# OpenFDA API: Can I perform search by same field with various values

Tags: api, openfda

I'm in a process of investigation of openFDA API and its possibilities.

For now I'm reviewing this type of request - One enforcement report of a certain health hazard class

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/enforcement.json?search=classification:"Class+I"
```

Is it possible to make a request which returns results for all Hazard classes?

When I tried to use such a query

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/enforcement.json?search=classification:"Class+I"+classification:"Class+II"
```

system returns results only for the last term (in current case "Class II")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct query syntax for an 'OR' search:

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/enforcement.json?search=classification:("Class+I"+OR+"Class+II")
```

I took a look and the result count equals the count of Class 1 + Class 2 so this should be what you were looking for.

More information on openFDA "API Basics" are at https://open.fda.gov/api/reference/#query-syntax though there was not a specific example for an OR search that had spaces in it.